# SQL query geting error after adding apostrophe '

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, sql-server

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        schoolname
        ,CASE 
            WHEN schoolcity IS NULL
                OR schoolcity = ''
                THEN ''
            ELSE (', ' + REPLACE(schoolcity, 'ã', 'a'))
            END
        ,CASE 
            WHEN schoolname IS NULL
                OR schoolstate = ''
                THEN ''
            ELSE (', ' + schoolstate)
            END
        ) AS schoolname
FROM schools
WHERE schoolname LIKE '"+filter+"%'
ORDER BY schoolname
```

This is my query inside the code. when I add a apostrophe in the filter from search bar the expected result is not showing.

Case:
Types children' and shows nothing

Expected:

Was to show schools name containing children'(children's). Can some one please Help?

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be happening is that your WHERE clause is being submitted as :

```
WHERE schoolname LIKE 'children'%'
```

The apostrophe that you entered is then being treated as the end of the value.  To include an additional apostrophe you need to have it escaped as a double apostrophe.

If you enter  at the search bar this should be interpreted as:

```
WHERE schoolname LIKE 'children''%'
```

Try those query options directly in SSMS and you will see the difference

Comment: I need to show the first occurrence of filter. and that too from code. if children's is typed then it wont show.

Comment: To get "children's" you will need to enter "children''s"  i.e. always use two single quotes where you want to have just 1 in the query

Comment: Also, to only get the first occurrence then you need to use SELECT TOP (1) etc

Answer (score 0):

for using apostrophe use two quotes like ''

simple query :

```
select schoolname from school where schoolname like 'children''%'
```

if you passing @filter as variable you can use

```
declare @filter nvarchar(20)

select CONCAT(schoolname, CASE WHEN schoolcity IS NULL OR schoolcity = '' THEN '' Else  (', ' + REPLACE(schoolcity,'ã','a')) 
END,CASE WHEN schoolname IS NULL OR schoolstate = '' THEN '' Else (', ' + schoolstate) END) as schoolname from schools where schoolname like % + @filter + % order by schoolname
```

Comment: Use TOP 1 : select top 1 schoolname from school where schoolname like 'children''%'

Comment: If my answer was helpful for you, you should consider accepting it by clicking check-mark @shijo J